# Issues with assigning class properties in inheritance situation

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a simplified example of the problem I am currently facing.

I have a class whose members may or may not run functions that need to access values from a table stored in a database. I obviously don't want to make a hundred unnecessary database calls, so I'm currently trying to come up with a solution that does the following:

1. Does not access the database more than once for a specific set of data.
2. Only accesses the database if the data is actually needed.

Now my first thought is to assign the data that I need to a class variable. That way each instance of the class does not have to make a new connection to the database to get the table, and instead the connection is only made once.

```
def get_data_from_db():
    # Placeholder function for database access
    return 4

class Foo1:
    dbtable = get_data_from_db()
```

This accomplishes goal 1 perfectly well, but since the database is accessed when the class is declared, before anything is actually ran, we may download something that never gets used.

My next attempt was to use class properties, which allowed me to accomplish both goals 1 and 2.

```
class classproperty(object):
    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.fget = fget
    def __get__(self, owner_self, owner_cls):
        return self.fget(owner_cls)

class Foo1:
    _dbtable = None
    @classproperty
    def dbtable(cls):
        if cls._dbtable is None:
            print('new assignment from class {}'.format(cls.__name__))
            cls._dbtable = get_data_from_db()
        return cls._dbtable
```

Now, the first time `Foo1.dbtable` is accessed, it runs `get_data_from_db()`, but each subsequent time it is accessed it uses the previously stored value.

However, I have run into a problem. I have multiple classes which inherit from my base class, and what I currently have does not work the way I want it to.

Let's add:

```
class Foo2(Foo1):
    pass

class Foo3(Foo1):
    pass
```

If we run the following code we get the desired outcome:

```
print(Foo1.dbtable)
print(Foo2.dbtable)
print(Foo3.dbtable)

> new assignment from class Foo1
> 4
> 4
> 4
```

The database call happens in Foo1's namespace, and later when it needs to be accessed in Foo2 and Foo3 it is already available. But Foo1 is a base class, and will probably never be actually instantiated. Instead we will probably run something like this:

```
print(Foo2.dbtable)
print(Foo3.dbtable)

> new assignment from class Foo2
> 4
> new assignment from class Foo3
> 4
```

Now I've run into a problem. When the database is accessed for the first time in Foo2, the results are stored in Foo2's namespace, which Foo3 does not have access to. Then, when Foo3 needs the same data, it makes a second database call, which is not the desired outcome.

I have no idea what the best method for solving this problem is though. My initial thoughts are to see if the following is possible. The current code I have is:

```
if cls._dbtable is None:
    cls._dbtable = get_data_from_db()
```

Instead of that, if `cls._dbtable` is None, I would traverse the class's mro in reverse order (starting with the class right before object) looking for the first class where `cls._dbtable` is defined. Presumably, that namespace will be the one which everything inherits `cls._dbtable` from. I would then place the downloaded data from the database in that namespace, instead of assigning it to the current class's namespace.

However, this idea seems like a super messy hack, so I was really hoping there was an easier solution.

Comment: Have you considered making `dbtable` its own class (including this lazy-fetch logic) and storing a reference to it in your `FooN`?

Comment: @Norrius: Wow that seems so obvious now that I think about it. This is why I keep you guys on stackoverflow around.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed like a hard problem, but in the comments Norrius suggested the very obvious solution of just making dbtable into its own class.

```
class DbTable:
    def __init__(self):
        self._db_table = None

    @property
    def dbtable(self):
        if self._db_table is None:
            print('new assignment')
            self._db_table = self.get_data_from_db()
        return self._db_table

    def get_data_from_db(self):
        # Placeholder function for database access
        return 4


class Foo1:
    db = DbTable()
    dbtable = db.dbtable

class Foo2(Foo1):
    pass

class Foo3(Foo1):
    pass
```

And it seems to have the functionality that I wanted.

```
print(Foo1.dbtable)
print(Foo2.dbtable)
print(Foo3.dbtable)

> new assignment
> 4
> 4
> 4

print(Foo2.dbtable)
print(Foo3.dbtable)

> new assignment
> 4
> 4
```

So thanks again Norrius for the simple and obvious suggestion that I was somehow overlooking. To everyone else, sorry that I bothered you with a problem that turned out to have a pretty trivial answer.